# Simplification of $\sqrt{(1-\cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta}$

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify the expression $$\sqrt{(1-\cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta}$$

I have done this way : $(1-\cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2 = 1-2\cos\alpha \cos\beta +\cos^2\alpha \cos^2\beta$

Please guide further....

Comment: Are you familiar with trig formulas like $\cos \alpha \cos \beta +/- \sin \alpha \sin \beta$? Also $2 \cos \alpha \beta = \cos(x-y) + \cos(x+y)$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\cos\alpha,b=\cos\beta$

So, the the given expression $$=\sqrt{(1-ab)^2-(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}=\sqrt{1-2ab+a^2b^2-(1-a^2-b^2+a^2b^2)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab}=|a-b|=|\cos\alpha-\cos\beta|$$

Comment: thanks that was great...thanks a lot..

Comment: @SachinSharmaa, my pleasure. I used $a,b$ to keep the calculation simple.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=\;}( 1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2 - \sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta \\
&= ( 1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2 - (\sin\alpha \sin\beta)^2 &(1) \\
&= ( 1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta)( 1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin\beta) &(2) \\
&= \left( 1 - (\cos\alpha \cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin\beta)\right)\left( 1 - (\cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha \sin\beta) \right) &(3)\\
&= \left( 1 - \cos(\alpha-\beta)\right)\left( 1 - \cos(\alpha+\beta) \right) &(4) \\
&= 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) \cdot 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) &(5) \\
&= 4 \sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) &(6) \\
&= \left( 2 \sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) \right)^2 &(7) \\
&= \left( \cos\beta - \cos\alpha \right)^2 &(8)
\end{align}$$

so that

$$
\sqrt{( 1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2 - \sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta} = \left| \cos\beta - \cos\alpha \right|$$

Steps:

1. Regroup
2. Difference of squares: $(x-y)^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$
3. Regroup
4. Angle Addition formulas for cosine
5. Half-angle formulas for sine
6. Simplification
7. Regroup
8. Product-to-Sum (well, *-Difference* here) "Prosthaphaeresis" formula

See [Wikipedia's "List of Trigonometric Identities" page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) for various formulas (especially the one for Step 8, which isn't so well known but comes in handy).

Comment: What is $\sqrt{4}$? $\pm 2$? No.

Comment: @Cortizol: $\sqrt{4}$ isn't $\pm 2$ (it's just $2$), but $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$ (whichever sign makes the variable result non-negative); but, of course, I should've used absolute value. Fixed.

Comment: that was great explanation .... really thankfull to you..

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}(1-\cos\alpha \cos\beta)^2-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta&=1+\cos^2{\alpha}\cos^2{\beta}-2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta\\
&=1+(1-\sin^2{\alpha)\cos^2{\beta}}-2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta\\
&=1+\cos^2{\beta}-\sin^2{\alpha\cos^2{\beta}}-2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}-\sin^2\alpha \sin^2\beta\\
&=1+\cos^2{\beta}-\sin^2{\alpha}-2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}\\
&=\cos^2{\beta}+\cos^2{\alpha}-2\cos{\alpha}\cos{\beta}\\
&=(\cos {\alpha}-\cos {\beta})^2\end{align*}
$$

So the answer will be $|\cos {\alpha}-\cos {\beta}|$

Comment: This isn't good. Look at second and third row, there is mistake: it should be $1+\cos^2 \beta$ instead $2+\cos^2 \beta$

Comment: So, your expression is equal to $(\cos \alpha - \cos \beta)^2$ which is much better solution if we agree :)